# Postman port forwarding to virtualbox VPN

Tags: postman, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vpn

I have to connect to company VPN to access the internal applications and to do the testing. Once I connect to VPN the internet gets disconnected, so I did the following setup.

I installed windows 10 in the Virtual Box (VM) and connects to the company VPN in the VM. Now I have the Physical Machine that is connected to Internet and the VM that is connected to VPN.

I want to forward all requests from POSTMAN in the Physical Machine to the Virtual Machine.